# Is there a way to find scaled density when display size increased to largest

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, accessibility, android-jetpack-compose

is there any to find to find largest display scale density? I need to show different layout if it is scaled up more than 170 percent. We are getting scaled density for currently set scaled diaplay only. By using DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE we are getting scaled density for default scale.

[Display scale image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4fU2.png)

Answer (score 0):

`LocalDensity.current` returns an object with properties to access these attributes, I imagine.

Comment: Yes, it is returning current configurations set. But i need the largest display scale so i can calculate how much percentage it has scaled/increased.